# ChromeDriver getting detected after first request

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium ChromeDriver to navigate to pages and it works fine, but on second request, I get intercepted by Incapsula.

If I dispose of the driver everytime, it works though.

Here's the current code:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments(new List<string>() { "headless" });

var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
```

The code below is in a loop which iterates over many records

```
//extract json variable from page output
ResultModel resultModel = new ResultModel();
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"https://www.website.ca{resultUrl}");
                
var modelString = driver.ExecuteScript("return JSON.stringify(window.the_variable);", new object[] { });

if (modelString != null)
    resultModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultModel>(modelString.ToString());

driver.Dispose();
```

So this works, but disposing and re-creating the driver everytime slows the process quite a bit.

When I try to simply `Navigate` to the next page, after the first request, I get intercepted.

What is happening exactly when I'm disposing and recreating ? Could I spoof that without actually doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the cookies seemed to have helped:

```
driver.ExecuteChromeCommand("Network.clearBrowserCookies", new Dictionary<string, object>() );
```